# How to upload multiple Images through Api

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload

I am trying to Upload Multiple Images through Api but i am not understanding how to send a list, I can upload a single image though. Tried alot of searches but does'nt helped, i also import multi_image_picker i can pick the images but the problem is in uploading.

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _uploadImage(File image) async {
   

    String value = '';
    SharedPreferences pref2 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    value = pref2.getString("user_role");

    final mimeTypeData =
        lookupMimeType(image.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');

    // Intilize the multipart request
    final imageUploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest('POST', apiUrl);

    // Attach the file in the request
    final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('photo', image.path,
        contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));
    // Explicitly pass the extension of the image with request body
    // Since image_picker has some bugs due which it mixes up
    // image extension with file name like this filenamejpge
    // Which creates some problem at the server side to manage
    // or verify the file extension


    imageUploadRequest.files.add(file);
    imageUploadRequest.fields['mobile'] = _mobileNo.text;

    imageUploadRequest.headers.addAll({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': Constants.authToken,
    });

    var response = await imageUploadRequest.send();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Done!');

    final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();

    return json.decode(respStr);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this an example of uploading files to your API with HTTP package

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void uploadFiles(List<File> files) async {
  final url = YOUR-API-LINK;

  for (var file in files) {
    // Create a multipart request
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));

    // Add the file to the request
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'file',
      file.readAsBytesSync(),
      filename: file.path.split('/').last,
    ));

    // Send the request
    var response = await request.send();

    // Check the status code
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print('Failed to upload file');
    }else{
    print response.body;
}
  }
}
```

for Dio use this

```dart
void uploadFiles(List<File> files) async {
  final url = YOUR-API-LINK;

  // Create a Dio client
  var dio = Dio();

  // Create a FormData object
  var formData = FormData();

  // Add the files to the FormData object
  for (var file in files) {
    formData.files.add(MapEntry(
      'file',
      await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename: file.path.split('/').last),
    ));
  }

  // Send the request
  var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData);

  // Check the status code
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    print('Failed to upload files');
  }else {
   print(response.data)
   }
}
```

as you can see there not much difference between them in http you use `MultipartRequest` in dio you use `FormData`.